# geom_point introducing shift in start of geom_polar pie (doughnut) chart

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pie-chart

While creating a pie chart with ggplot2 I stumbled over a weird behavior of the start of the polar coordinate plot. If we take

```
dta <- data.frame(val = 1:60, col = rep(c(0,1), each = 10))
```

and make a pie chart using

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dta, aes(x = val, y = 2, fill = factor(col), color = factor(col))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_polar(start = 0)
```

we end up with a pie chart as expected: 
[image]

Say, we want to create a little doughnut hole in the middle of the chart, we can achieve that by adding a point in the middle:

```
ggplot(dta, aes(x = val, y = 2, fill = factor(col), color = factor(col))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_polar(start = 0) + 
  geom_point(aes(0,0), size = 30, color = "lightgrey", show.legend = FALSE)
```

However, this point introduces a strange shift of the start of the pie chart resulting in a small grey sector at the top.

[image]

Why is this shift caused? How can it be avoided?  Btw. this shift is also introduced by other geoms like `geom_vline(xintercept = 0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shift looks like it's from `?scale_x_continuous()`. Its `expand` argument says, "The defaults are c(0.05, 0) for continuous variables, and c(0, 0.6) for discrete variables.".

So if you want to eliminate that gap, you could define your `geom_point()` layer outside of `aes()` to prevent `scale_x_continuous` getting involved there:

```
ggplot(dta, aes(x = val, y = 2, fill = factor(col), color = factor(col))) + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_polar(start = 0) +
    geom_point(x = 0, y = 0, size = 30, color = "lightgrey", show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Or tweak the values passed to the `expand` argument:

```
ggplot(dta, aes(x = val, y = 2, fill = factor(col), color = factor(col))) + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_polar(start = 0) + 
    geom_point(aes(0,0), size = 15, color = "lightgrey", show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,-.25))
```

I'm not sure why `c(0,0)` doesn't yield the desired output...

[image]

For the `geom_vline()` case (again not sure why this works, `coord_polar()` is finicky fella) we can add `geom_vline(xintercept = .5)`, to either strategy above, and get an appropriately placed vertical line:

```
ggplot(dta, aes(x = val, y = 2, fill = factor(col), color = factor(col))) + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_polar(start = 0) +
    geom_point(x = 0, y = 0, size = 30, color = "lightgrey", show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = .5)
```

[image]

I think the first strategy is better since the second appears to be sightly tilting the color boundaries (and vline) away from "true" vertical. Didn't see that on the first pass in the small preview window..

Comment: Thanks man, that works fine. However, I use an additional `geom_vline`, which also causes the error. Do you have an idea how to adapt the first solution on `geom_vline`?

Comment: what parameters are you passing to the `geom_vline()`?

Comment: `geom_vline(xintercept = 0)`

Comment: used another hack to get a vline on there, maybe that works for your case? `coord_polar` is weird, perhaps using an alternative plot type would be easier

Comment: Thanks so much. Seems to be some strange problem, or a really annoying design choice.